# Render view with id in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way to render view with `ID`? 
It renders `/blogs/test` fine for a test, but not with `ID`.

```
    $response = $this->render('/blogs/update_favorite/'.$blog['Blog']['id']);
    // $response = $this->render('/blogs/test');
         echo $response;
```

However it works with `requestAction`:

```
    $response = $this->requestAction('/blogs/update_favorite' .'/'. $blog['Blog']['id'], array('return'));
         echo $response;
```

But I heard that `requestAction` is not a good idea in cakephp with lots of traffic.

Comment: Could you supply some sources where you heard these statements? Also, what are your own experiences with requestAction? Validate your own case inb4 assuming things.

Comment: I'm trying to ajax to set favorites,... and render small file with image that favorited. And I read it here when google it,... can't find that statement anymore,... thank you